# Web Application Architecture with Video Conferencing, Instant Messaging and File Sharing

Tags: socket.io, file-sharing, flash-media-server, livechat, video-conferencing

I'm currently planning a web application ( Social Network ), where people can share knowledge on a specific subject for a client. The knowledge share is going to be provided using real-time communication (audio, video conferences, talks, live chats, sharing files). If possible, the solution should be compatible with modern desktop and mobile browsers.

In my research for real-time communication implementations, I came across Socket.IO (http://socket.io) and I saw several examples of chat-roulettes. I also came across this page: http://myprojectguide.org/p/flash-videoio/index.html and the examples (http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/).

Socket.IO degrades to the available transport (if not WebSocket, then Flash Socket, then polling, then etc.). I've read a lot, but I can't seem to build the picture in my mind: How would I go to fulfill the project requirements stated above? Would I go for it by using Node.JS and Socket IO only, do I have to also run a Media Server for Audio/Video operations? In other words, how does the Media server come together with the Socket.IO server?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since i see that you are targetting mobile browsers too.. You need HTML5.

> HTML5 is a set of web standards being developed by the "Web Hypertext
>   Application Technology Working Group"
>
> The HTML5 standard includes many new features for more dynamic web
>   applications and interfaces. One such component being specified and
>   implemented is the  element.
>
> Using an HTML5 Javascript Library, your videos can be played back on
>   the latest mobile devices and even on older browsers that require
>   Flash.

To get you started with .. 
http://html5video.org/wiki/Getting_Started_-_Navigating_HTML5